# How does .net / C# decide which library is loaded as a shared resource and which as private per domain and how can I control this behavior?

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-framework-version

I am trying to understand how C#/.net FW decides how to load assemblies/types to be shared or not shared across AppDomains.

I know this can be somewhat controlled using the LoaderOptimization Enum but it only seems to affect how assemblies/types are loaded and doesn't explain how to make a type that will be loaded as shared or not.

From what I can see, some types are always loaded as shared no matter what (such as String), some can be loaded either shared or not depending on LoaderOptimization (such as Process) and some can never be shared (HttpSessionStateWrapper).

So the questions are,
How can I tell if a specific type can or can't be shared?
How can I tell is a specific type is currently shared or not in runtime?
How can I create a library that will then be always shared when loaded by multiple domains?

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to ask, but maybe access modifiers is the thing you are looking for? `public` for everyone, `internal` for it's own domain only. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: You know AppDomains don't really exist in .NET Core/.NET 5 and later? It's probably not the right concept to be investing time in working with in 2022.

Comment: I am aware that AppDomains are gone in .net5+ however, I am trying to write an application that attaches itself to other applications and I need to support .net FW with AppDomains.
The application is pretty complex and "steals" function pointers using a library called Monomod. The stealing of the pointers is very dependent on whether the library is or isn't shared and whether it can or can't be shared.